# Sphinx delta indexing with one search server and multiple clients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sphinx, passenger, thinking-sphinx

I've a multihost environment with multiple web-server and one search server.

It seems that delta indexing working only on the server, on which actually searchd works. Is there any way to make delta-indexing work for all web server?

Comment: Please can you explain the problem a bit more? What are you indexing? MySQL data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the delayed delta approach for delta indexing - and have Delayed Job running on the same server as searchd and your index files. Delta indexing must be centralised, and this is the best way to manage it.

Of course, if you're using a different job processing library (resque, workling, etc), it shouldn't be too hard to write your own version of ts-delayed-delta that behaves in the same way. There is a gem for Workling and TS though - and maybe resque, possibly others.